# I have no sound on my laptop (Huawei Matebook 15D)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I recently installed ubuntu on my new laptop and i have no sound. I had the same problem when trying linux mint. In alsamixer there is only one item called S/PDIF. The sound chip is ATI R6xx HDMI.
When opening pavucontrol its stuck in Establishing connection to Pulse Audio. Please wait...

In alsamixer in the upper left is written: Item: S/PDIF [off]. I dont know if thats the issue but i have no idea how to turn it on in the F1 help section there is not button for it, arrow key etc dont work. The only output device is called Dummy Output.

Im using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Whats your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Im using 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: what happens if you try settings> sound> output-device> and choose the actual output device you expect should work ?

Comment: That looks not promising. `sudo lshw -c multimedia` please [edit] your question for output.

Comment: Could it be that the underlying Huawei Hardware only works with Windows 11? I tried windows 10 after this and wifi suddenly stopped working alswell. When installing Windows 11 after a short use of the troubleshooter everything worked perfectly fine again. Thatd be a real bummer.